# how to compare strings of a variable, by keys of an array, and make the exchange for values of another array?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have two very large arrays! I need every time a key value is found from array1 to be changed by the string variable, it is changed by a value of a key from array2.

```
$array1 = array("worda" ,"wordb","wordc","worde","wordd");
 $array2 = array("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4","word5");
    $myVar = '"worda wordb house wordc chair worde woman wordd wall'; 
    $string = in_array($myVar, $array1);
    if($myVar ==  $string){
       $myVar =  array_replace_recursive($array1,$array2);
       print_r($myVar);
    }
// expected output: word1 word2 house word3 chair word4 woman word5 wall
```

**there are several similar issues to being, well duplicated, as stackoverflow showed me, but none have anything like that.**

Thanks.

Comment: Post the output you expect from this code sample.

Comment: @Nic it's there already, last line in code

Comment: Ah crap, sorry, missed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode myvar and use array_search to find the key where a match is found.
Then use the key to replace the myvar-array.

```
$array1 = array("worda" ,"wordb","wordc","worde","wordd");
$array2 = array("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4","word5");
$myVar = 'worda wordb house wordc chair worde woman wordd wall'; 
$arr = explode(" ",$myVar);
Foreach($arr as &$word){
    $key = array_search($word, $array1);
    If($key !== false){
        $word = $array2[$key];
    }
}

Echo implode(" ", $arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/i8SV0

---

Or you can use array combine to create an array with array1 value as key and array2 value as value.
That way you replace the word easier if the array key exists.

```
$array1 = array("worda" ,"wordb","wordc","worde","wordd");
$array2 = array("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4","word5");
$combine = array_combine($array1,$array2);
$myVar = 'worda wordb house wordc chair worde woman wordd wall'; 
$arr = explode(" ",$myVar);
Foreach($arr as &$word){
    If(isset($combine[$word])) $word = $combine[$word];
}

Echo implode(" ", $arr)
```